# Have a trouble with python import

Tags: python

I have an app:

```
/app
    /folder1/file_one.py
    /folder2/file_two.py
    /folder3/file_three.py
PYTHONPATH ~/app
```

When I try to import `function1` from `file_one.py` to `file_two.py` everything works correctly, but when I try:

```
import function1 from file_one.py to file_three.py I get the message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu18/rex/app/folder3/file_three.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder1.file_one import function1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'
```

This problem occurs all the time, and I always solve it in different ways, but nothing works right now. I tried:

```
-PYTHONPATH
-relative and absolute path
-__init.py__
```

Comment: See [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/4450498)

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'
```

So do what it asks you for and turn `folder1` into the module.
This is done by adding `__init__.py` file into the `folder1`. Do the same thing with other project directories and you will avoid the problem with imports.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the same file structure as yours

   [image]
2. An error occurred when directly `from file_one import function1` in **file_two**

   [image]

##### Solution:

Add the following code at the top of the **file_two**:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("../folder1")
```

The script executes normally without error

[image]

If you still want to eliminate the yellow wavy line warning, add the following configuration in the **workspace *settings.json***:

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./folder1"
    ]
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure the relative path of everything is good. If you are using that file as an import its relative path will remain the same.

Comment: This is neither a working solution nor does it correctly represent what the OP tried to do. Note that their attempted syntax in the traceback is `from folder1.file_one import function1`, which is actually closer to correct than this suggestion...

Comment: Also, some people/projects follow a certain file/folder structure, where similar components are grouped by folder (=modules) and putting everything in 1 folder is not allowed. The question looks like just a simplified minimal example of their actual code.

Comment: `from file_one.py import function1` Import statement definitely DO NOT need `.py` at the end of the module name.